# How can I debug this Macvim rendering bug?

Tags: debugging, vim, macvim

Apologies if the question isn't succinct or globally useful.

I recently updated to Mavericks from Snow Leopard and brought over all of my toolchain.
So, this is how my editor typically looks like:

[image: a fullscreen macvim session]

My workflow typically involves heavy usage of the [command-t plugin](https://github.com/wincent/Command-T). For those unaware, it's a fuzzy file system searcher. When it's invoked it typically looks like this:

[image: macvim with command-t]

However, post Mavericks I have started getting these weird, hard to reproduce rendering bugs that are triggered with command-t. When the "fuzzy search selection 'drawer'" gets activated, occasionally the whole bits of the app will gain a black "highlight".

Case in point:

[image: screenshot of malfunctioning macvim]

([full resolution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ow24P.png))

It's only triggered occasionally; right now it seems to correlate while fullscreened on my external monitor. Most of the time it works just fine and then it stings me, and I have yet to been able to discern any pattern to it.

It's quite frustrating; see for yourself:

[image: gif of macvim rendering bug]

Furthermore, it's also triggered with the [ctrl-p](https://github.com/kien/ctrlp.vim) plugin (another fuzzy file system searcher). It seems that whatever draws a "buffer that overlays your code buffers" is what triggers it, and is not specific to the command-t plugin.

This only started happening after I moved to Mavericks; my identical setup worked in an earlier MacVim snapshot in Snow Leopard.

I've posted this question in the hopes that this might seem recognizable to someone; I'm currently in the process of bisecting my bundle folder hoping that perhaps it's triggered by something else.

I have yet to try downgrading my MacVim snapshot (currently: 72; previous one was ~54). You can find my [vimrc here](https://github.com/phillmv/dotfiles/blob/master/home/.vimrc), my [.vim folder here](https://github.com/phillmv/dotfiles/tree/master/home/.vim) and here is info on my macvim:

```
maryanne:~ $ mvim --version
VIM - Vi IMproved 7.4 (2013 Aug 10, compiled Mar 24 2014 11:26:57)
MacOS X (unix) version
Included patches: 1-52
Compiled by Homebrew
Huge version with MacVim GUI.  Features included (+) or not (-):
+acl             +file_in_path    +mouse_sgr       +tag_binary
+arabic          +find_in_path    -mouse_sysmouse  +tag_old_static
+autocmd         +float           +mouse_urxvt     -tag_any_white
+balloon_eval    +folding         +mouse_xterm     +tcl
+browse          -footer          +multi_byte      +terminfo
++builtin_terms  +fork()          +multi_lang      +termresponse
+byte_offset     +fullscreen      -mzscheme        +textobjects
+cindent         -gettext         +netbeans_intg   +title
+clientserver    -hangul_input    +odbeditor       +toolbar
+clipboard       +iconv           +path_extra      +transparency
+cmdline_compl   +insert_expand   +perl            +user_commands
+cmdline_hist    +jumplist        +persistent_undo +vertsplit
+cmdline_info    +keymap          +postscript      +virtualedit
+comments        +langmap         +printer         +visual
+conceal         +libcall         +profile         +visualextra
+cryptv          +linebreak       +python          +viminfo
+cscope          +lispindent      -python3         +vreplace
+cursorbind      +listcmds        +quickfix        +wildignore
+cursorshape     +localmap        +reltime         +wildmenu
+dialog_con_gui  -lua             +rightleft       +windows
+diff            +menu            +ruby            +writebackup
+digraphs        +mksession       +scrollbind      -X11
+dnd             +modify_fname    +signs           -xfontset
-ebcdic          +mouse           +smartindent     +xim
+emacs_tags      +mouseshape      -sniff           -xsmp
+eval            +mouse_dec       +startuptime     -xterm_clipboard
+ex_extra        -mouse_gpm       +statusline      -xterm_save
+extra_search    -mouse_jsbterm   -sun_workshop    -xpm
+farsi           +mouse_netterm   +syntax
   system vimrc file: "$VIM/vimrc"
     user vimrc file: "$HOME/.vimrc"
 2nd user vimrc file: "~/.vim/vimrc"
      user exrc file: "$HOME/.exrc"
  system gvimrc file: "$VIM/gvimrc"
    user gvimrc file: "$HOME/.gvimrc"
2nd user gvimrc file: "~/.vim/gvimrc"
    system menu file: "$VIMRUNTIME/menu.vim"
  fall-back for $VIM: "/Applications/MacVim.app/Contents/Resources/vim"
Compilation: clang -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DFEAT_GUI_MACVIM -Wall -Wno-unknown-pragmas -pipe  -DMACOS_X_UNIX -no-cpp-precomp  -g -O2 -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1     -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Tcl.framework/Headers  -D_REENTRANT=1  -D_THREAD_SAFE=1  -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE=1
Linking: clang   -L. -L/usr/local/lib -L. -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.6/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/config -F/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.6/Frameworks -L/usr/local/lib -o Vim -framework Cocoa -framework Carbon       -lm  -lncurses -liconv -framework Cocoa   -fstack-protector -L/usr/local/lib  -L/System/Library/Perl/5.16/darwin-thread-multi-2level/CORE -lperl -framework Python  -F/System/Library/Frameworks -framework Tcl -framework CoreFoundation -framework Ruby
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I cannot make out what is happening in your screenshot.  Can you explain how to reproduce this using vanilla vim commands, no plugins?  (That is the first step in debugging, after all.)

Comment: I was in a rush at work while filling this out and not thinking clearly. I've gone back and added more screenshots and details. I cannot reproduce this without using a plugin, so I will next test whether it's reproducible with a minimum set of active plugins.

Comment: Known issue? https://code.google.com/p/macvim/issues/detail?id=409

Comment: Disabling the advanced renderer has stopped the issue from springing up. Thanks!, I will definitely dig through there.